# What game is this PS4 avatar soldier with a yellow helmet from?

Tags: game-identification

One of my friends on PS4 has this picture for his Avatar:

[image: soldier with rifle and cracked yellow helmet]

What game is this from? My first thought was that it sorta looks like [Deathstroke from Arkham Origins](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L0BkB7ROYc4/maxresdefault.jpg). But it's clearly not him because Deathstroke has an orange mask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is from the game *Haze*, released in 2008 for the Playstation 3.

[image: PS3 boxart for Haze]

Answer (score 10):

Apparently it is Shane Carpenter, from the video game [Haze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haze_(video_game)).

[image: Box image for the PS3 version of the video game Haze]